# Callback into a file then JSON this file

Tags: javascript, json, callback, onvif

I use onvif package to control my camera.

But to analyse the output I need to have a JSON file.

For the moment my output is on the console, but I'm a newby and I don't know how to put this in a file and JSON it.

Here is my program:

```
var CAMERA_HOST = 'IP',
    USERNAME = 'USER',
    PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD',
    PORT = 'PORT';


var http = require('http'),
    Cam = require('./onvif').Cam;
new Cam({
    hostname: CAMERA_HOST,
    username: USERNAME,
    password: PASSWORD,
    port: PORT
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
            console.log('Connection Failed for ' + CAMERA_HOST + ' Port: ' + PORT + ' Username: ' + USERNAME + ' Password: ' + PASSWORD);
            return;
    }
console.log('CONNECTED');
this.getImagingSettings({VideoSourceToken:'000'},function(err, stream) {
console.log(stream);
});
});
```

It works and I got this on the console:

```
CONNECTED
{ brightness: 50,
colorSaturation: 50,
contrast: 50,
exposure: { mode: 'MANUAL', iris: 0.995633 },
focus: { autoFocusMode: 'MANUAL', defaultSpeed: 1 },
sharpness: 50 }
```

Now how can I get a JSON file out of it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It looks like `stream` is an object, so to turn it to JSON, use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: stream is the object but it is not a file. I want to make a file with the content of stream and then JSON.stringify it Possible?

Comment: if the content is a javscript object, then, yes, you can JSON.stringify it ... if not, then you'll have a hard time

Comment: I've realised the JSON.stringify but now i want to export it in test.json Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this by adding these commands:

```
fs.writeFile('Dgetimage.json', JSON.stringify(stream), function (err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log('Sauvergardé!');
});
```

It save the json answer on the Dgetimage.json document (same folder as the javascript program)